# Why is an IllegalBlockSizeException thrown when testing FingerprintManager in a simulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, fingerprint

I'm trying to test out the new [Fingerprint authentication](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#fingerprint-authentication) APIs in Android M, I can register fingerprints with the OS, use the registered fingerprints to receive AuthenticationCallback#onAuthenticationSucceeded(), but trying to validate access to the keystore (**mCipher.doFinal(SECRET_MESSAGE.getBytes())**) results in an IllegalBlockSizeException rather than the expected result of the encryption succeeding.

This is being tested in the simulator running M pre-release, I don't know of any in-market devices that have support for M with a physical fingerprint reader yet...

I tested using my own code as well as the [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) produced by Google.

Any ideas if there's extra steps not listed (or that I skipped)?
Is this just not supported in the simulator today or at all due to no TEE?